# Applying class to jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery ui dialog  which is initialised like this

```
jQuery("#dialog-message").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width:500,
    buttons: {  Ok: function () {jQuery(this).dialog("close");  }}
});
```

This is opened when clicking on specified span id as given below

```
jQuery(document).delegate("#samno","click",function () {
    var usin=jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery.post("scripts/sample_counts.php",{"usin":usin}, function(data) {
        jQuery('#dialog-message').html(data);
        jQuery('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });     
});
```

Actual div of this message is this:

```
<div id="dialog-message" class="dialog"  title="Counting Data"></div>
```

Following css are also there in the page:

```
  .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {  display: none;}

  div.ui-dialog {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
  }

  .ui-dialog.table {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

The data received from post request contains a table. I defined a class called msg_tble and tried to apply this on the table. But it is not working.

Any idea how to use css for the table in the dialog box?

As suggested by Arun P Johny I am sharing the table markup

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Counting Date</th><th>System ID</th><th>Counting    Time(Sec)</th><th>CPM</th></tr>";
                while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($result3)){

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$data2['count_date']."</ts>";
                echo "<td>".$data2['counter_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$data2['count_time']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$data2['cpm']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                }
                echo "</table>";
```

Comment: sidenote: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: `jQuery("#dialog-message").find("table").addClass("msg_tble")` didn't work?

Comment: I am wonder if your rule `.ui-dialog.table` is supposed to be `.ui-dialog .table` (notice the space).

Comment: can you share the css for `msg_tble` and the table markup

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
.ui-dialog.table {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #a9c6c9;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Try:

```
#dialog-message table {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #a9c6c9;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

With jQueryUI dialogs, the dialog contents behave exactly as if they are part of the "dialog" DIV.

That is, whatever div you use for the dialog -- any styling you do on that div, or on the contents of that div, will be reflected in the dialog. Just style the contents as part of the `#dialog-message` div and forget about the fact that they are in a dialog, *and true happiness will be yours.*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4g979c0/)</kbd>

---

Edit:

I just read the comments below your question and I see that Austin Mullins has a solution that should work, and it answers your question about adding a class to the table-within-the-dialog.  I hope he will add it as an answer so it can be upvoted.

But yes, it really is that simple. <sub>*Quiet appreciation for John R*</sub>

Comment: LOL, I didn't think about just fixing the CSS! I like that better, but for your sake I'll add my fiddle to the collection.

Comment: @gibberish, your suggestion is not working for me. Austin Mullin's suggestion is also not working

Comment: @mansoondreamz Glad you solved it.  See, it was as simple as styling the div. :)

Answer (score 0):

The effectiveness of this approach depends on what exactly is returned by "sample_counts.php". In my [testing on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/4kufxm1t/2/), I discovered two different approaches that work in different situations.

If the `<table>` element is the *root* of the document, the following works:

```
function(data) {
    $dialog = jQuery('#dialog-message');
    $data = $(data);
    $data.addClass("msg-table");

    $dialog.html($data).dialog('open');
    return false;
}
```

In this test, I had the echo endpoint return the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Usin</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Samno</td></tr>
</table>
```

Notice that, in this case, we expect the table by itself with no surrounding containers. If, on the other hand, the table is part of a larger document, the following works:

```
function(data) {
    $dialog = jQuery('#dialog-message');
    $data = $(data).find("table");
    $data.addClass("msg-table");

    $dialog.html($data).dialog('open');
    return false;
}
```

Note the use of the `find()` function to get to the first `<table>` element. Here's the example HTML used to test it:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><th>Usin</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Samno</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: "sample_counts.php" returns only the table and I edited my question to include this part. To make the point in simpler terms, I just put it like this :- A page containing several records is displayed. The user click on a particular record, then the click function is triggered. sample_counts.php s will query a database, get data, format it into a table and send back. jquery add this table to the dialog div and the div is opened." In this scenario, there is no css included in the table echoed by sample_counts.php. All css are in the main page.

Comment: Not working... Also I do not understand What is $dialog and $data. is it php or javascript? In your fiddle it is working but in my script , it is showing error

Comment: It's all JavaScript. Sometimes it's conventional to put a $ at the beginning of jQuery variables. They're just variables, you could call them anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use 'dialogClass' property.    
     $( ".selector" ).dialog({
        dialogClass: "alert"
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added the following css in the main page

```
div#dialog-message table {
    margin: 1em 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

div#dialog-message table td,  div#dialog-message table th {

    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-color:#CC0033;

    padding: .6em 10px;

    text-align: left;

}
```

this solved the problem. No other changes made. Thank you every one who gave suggestions/answers